# Extract text before a specific word with hive

Tags: regex, string, hadoop, text, hive

I have data in a column that looks like below :

- Avenue 1 HE1 345 HOUSE 123.
- FLAT 202 HRE2 D34 HOUSE 345.
- DOOR 324 HA1 345 HOUSE 67

5.

I need to extract the postcode which comes always before house varying between 6-7 characters in all the cases. There's always a white space before HOUSE and in between postcode and one before postcode.

Desired output :

- HE1 345
- HRE2 D34
- HA1 345

I've tried using substring_index two times only to know that hive doesn't support the function. I'm pretty much novice to Hive. Help and any reference to material will be a great gesture too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've tried using substring_index two times only to know that hive doesn't support the function" https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern `' (\\w+ \\w+) HOUSE'`. This means one space, one or more word characters, one space, one or more characters, one space, HOUSE. In the parentheses is a group to be extracted. Group index is 1.

**Demo:**

```
 select regexp_extract(s,' (\\w+ \\w+) HOUSE',1) 
from
(select 'Avenue 1 HE1 345 HOUSE 123.'  s union all
select 'FLAT 202 HRE2 D34 HOUSE 345.' s union all
select 'DOOR 324 HA1 345 HOUSE 67'    s) s;
OK
HE1 345
HRE2 D34
HA1 345
Time taken: 26.472 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

**For case insensitive use `(?i)` modifier:**

```
hive>
    >
    > select regexp_extract(s,' (\\w+ \\w+) (?i)HOUSE',1)
    > from
    > (select 'Avenue 1 HE1 345 HOUSe 123.'  s union all
    > select 'FLAT 202 HRE2 D34 HOUsE 345.' s union all
    > select 'DOOR 324 HA1 345 HOuSE 67'    s) s;
OK
HE1 345
HRE2 D34
HA1 345
```

See regex docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

About case insensitive: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: @ DuduMarkovitz Sure, `{1} ` quantifier can be omitted.  `select regexp_extract(s,' (\\w+ \\w+) HOUSE',1) `

Comment: @leftjoin Thanks a lot! Just to add what if house isn't case sensitive. Like House or HOUSE or hOuSE or house!

Answer (score -4):

You can save that file as csv file (Copy the contents in notepad and save that with .csv extension).

Now you can create table in hive and load data from csv file in the table.

**hive> create table text(column1 string,column2 string,column3 string,column4 string,column5 string, column6 string) Row format delimited fields terminated by ' '      ;**
OK
Time taken: 0.137 seconds

For loading data into table :
Use 
**hive> load data LOCAL inpath 'location of you file ' overwrite into table text;**

hive> load data LOCAL inpath '/home/cloudera/FinalProjects/text.csv' overwrite into table text;
Loading data to table default.text
Table default.text stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=84, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 0.59 seconds

**hive> select column3, column4 from text;**
OK
HE1 345
HRE2    D34
HA1 345
Time taken: 0.145 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)